# why object removed after some-time

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, singleton, durandal

I'm writing an application in Durandal. (C# is server-side, and Javascript+HTML are client-side).

On the server-side I create a `CacheManager` class.

I forced this class to have a single-instance (singleton). In the class I have one member called `cache`. This is the dictionary that holds the data of my application. The data is accumulated during run-time, when users open and close the application.

Here is my code:

```
public class CacheManager
{
    #region Singleton
    // static holder for instance, need to use lambda to construct since constructor private
    private static readonly Lazy<CacheManager> _instance = new Lazy<CacheManager>(() => new CacheManager());

    // private to prevent direct instantiation.
    private CacheManager()
    {
        Cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    // accessor for instance
    public static CacheManager Instance
    {
        get
        {

            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Cache { get; set; }

    #endregion
    //...continue application code
}
```

However, if it's been a long time since the last request sent to the server, on the next time when request arrives, it finds the dictionary object empty!

It seems like object in c# has limited lifetime, and when this time is over, the singleton is re-initialized, and dictionary accepts a new empty instance.

Comment: How long is a long time?  If it's getting on for a day, IIS could be recycling your app pool

Comment: I don't run at IIS, I'm in middle of the developing

Comment: Where do you test you app? IIS Express is default web browser for VS2012 and higher (when you press F5/ctrl+F5).

Answer (score 3):

IIS restarts app pool process if there is no requests for some time or memory limit reached or just some timeout.

Comment: I don't run on IIS yet, I'm in middle of the developing. and about the other suggestions- " or memory limit reached or just some timeout."- can you explein more about it?

Comment: about app pool recycling - http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling

Comment: NO, I wrote you that I know that "about app pool recycling" is not the problem becouse I don't run on IIS, and I ask you to explain more aboute "memory limit reached or just some timeout".

Comment: @user2783091, it's config of IIS, if app pool gets lots of memory, then it is restarted. Or by timeout. Default timeout for recycling is 1740 minutes.

Comment: And you didnt write how you run your app?

Comment: Are you running it on XSP or Apache then?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I run at localhost. I have WebConfig at cloent-side. It has line: <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /> do you think it is the matter? but it is on client-side! who can it be?

Comment: @user2783091 You do realize that Visual Studio 2012+ runs IIS Express as your web server when debugging by default, don't you? I assume that's what IDE you are using. So, you **are** running IIS. Your object is being recycled. My recommendation is to store session state on the client, not the server.